# What is the probability that a sample belongs to a particular random variable?

Tags: marginal-probability

Edited for clarity.

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with a known probability distribution. Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the probability that $\mathbf{v}$ is a sample of $X$?

Comment: Zero, because there are an infinite number of rv's $v$ can come from.

Comment: The problem relates to training a neural network to produce samples belonging to some particular random variable. So when the network yields a sample, how "good" is it at belonging to the actual random variable? That is required for the loss function during training.

Comment: @JMP : In infinite number of WHAT?? We are speaking here of just _one_ random variable, not an infinite number of them. It is asserted to have a continuous distribution. That implies the probability that it is equal to a specified number is $0.$ However, the poster said $v$ is a "sample of real numbers", and I wonder what that means. In particular, I wonder if the poster meant a _set_ of real numbers. Could the question mean "What is the probability that $X$ is a member of the set $v$?"? If, for example, $v$ were the interval from $2$ to $3,$ then that probability could be positive.

Comment: Normally, for good reasons, one learns the theory of probability before learning the theory behind "fitting", so it seems a bit odd to say that that is the "reverse" of something that is "typical". You throw a die; What is the probability that you get a $1\text{?}$ That seems to be what you're calling "reverse fitting." $\qquad$

Comment: At this, point, it seems some work will be needed before I can be sure what it is you're asking.

Comment: Try 'given $n$ rv's, and sample came from one, which one?'

Comment: @JMP : ok, Now that makes some sense.

Comment: @JMP : But you said it has a known distribution. How can it have a known distribution when the question asks for the probability that the distribution was one of a family of distributions?

Comment: You said "given $n$ random variables". Did you intend these to have different probability distributions?

Comment: OK @MichaelHardy I have tried to clarify the question with an edit. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ok, You said in a comment "given $n$ random variables". There's nothing about that in the question as it now stands. Does your comment about "$n$ random variables" still apply?

Comment: @MichaelHardy
No, "n random variables" does not.

Comment: At this point I can still only guess what you're asking. Here's another guess: You have $n$ independent copies of $X,$ i.e. $n$ independent random variables all of which have the same known probability distribution. Call them $X_1,\ldots,X_n.$ And you're asking for $\Pr( (X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \mathbf v). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Correct. If the X stochastic vector consisted of independent random variables then it would be: $f_{X,Y} = f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(x)$, but now that they are identical, I can't see how to compute it.